# Passing parameters to Route : Missing required parameters for [Route: post] error

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am trying to pass a parameter `id` from my view to the route. I my view `blog.blade.php`, I did the following :

```
<a href="{{ route('post', ['id' => $post->id ] ) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More </a>
```

My route looks like :

```
Route::get('blog/post/{id}', [
  'uses' =>  'PostController@getPost',
  'as' => 'post'
]);
```

And my controller action looks like :

```
public function getPost( $id)
{
    $post = Post::where('id','=',$id)->with('likes')->with('user')->first();
    return view('section.blog', ['post' => $post]);
}
```

But whenever I load the page I get the following error

> Missing required parameters for [Route: post] [URI: blog/post/{id}]. (View: D:\Web Development\ACES\resources\views\section\blog.blade.php)

I checked whether the value of `$post->id` exists by displaying it on the view and it **exists**

**More**
I tried removing the `{id}` part from the route and made it like

```
Route::get('blog/post/', [
  'uses' =>  'PostController@getPost',
  'as' => 'post'
]);
```

The Page loads but the link looks like :

```
http://localhost/blog/post?id=2
```

Then I get error in Controller

Why is this happening ? Why is the parameter not being passed to the route?
I am using Laravel 5.7

## Update

`php artisan route:list` looks like this

```
    +--------+----------+---------------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                             | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+---------------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                               | home             | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | about-us                        | about            | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | aces-admin                      | admin.home       | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | aces-admin/all-posts            | admin.allposts   | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | aces-admin/all-users            | admin.allusers   | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | aces-admin/edit-events          | admin.events     | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | aces-admin/edit-messages        | admin.messages   | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | aces-admin/edit-study-materials | admin.study      | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | aces-admin/manage-photos        | admin.photos     | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user                        |                  | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | blog                            | blog             | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@getIndex                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | blog/create                     | create           | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | blog/post/{id}                  | post             | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@getPost                            | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | events                          | event            | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | gallery                         | gallery          | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                           | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | login                           |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | logout                          | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web          |
|        | POST     | password/email                  | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset                  | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | password/reset                  | password.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token}          | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | register                        | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | register                        |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest    |
+--------+----------+---------------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: is post route under a route group ? if is can you add parent route group ?

Comment: Hei, if you inspect the a element how does the link look?

Comment: @Teoman The post route is not under any route group.

Comment: @Răducanu I have already stated that in the question. With the route like `Route::get('blog/post/{id}', .... ` I get the error and laravel error page is displayed. (So I can't find how link looks). But if I remove `{id}` fron route and make it like `Route::get('blog/post/', .... ` , the link looks like `http://localhost/blog/post?id=2`

Comment: @Xitish if you still wish to debug this you could set it optional param with ? ( {id?} ) and see the generated url.

Answer (score 1):

Try your second method and update your controller like below.

```
public function getPost(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->get('id');
    $post = Post::where('id','=',$id)->with('likes')->with('user')->first();
    return view('section.blog', ['post' => $post]);
}
```

Comment: That didn't help

Comment: Can you post the "php artisan route:list" result here ?

Comment: It's really weird, mate. Your code looks okay to me.

Comment: The problem seems to be in passing parameter `id` from view to the route. How does changing the controller action help here?

Comment: In your second method, You don't pass parameter. You pass a request.  as your route don't have any parameter http://localhost/blog/post?id=2.  So, you can access the id by request and that's why i updated your controller code. Just try it.

Comment: Can you share, What was your problem ? And how do you solved it ?

Comment: It was a silly mistake. I had a two references to `post` route in my view. I was unaware of the first reference which was called without passing the parameter. That was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To view your post, you don't need to use a route in your anchor tag. Try this:

```
<a href="/blog/post{{ $post->id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More </a>
```

Laravel will automaticlly pickup the ID if you have set up your controller correctly.

Answer (score 0):

define your route in this form :

```
Route::get('blog/post/{id}', 'PostController@getPost')->name('post');
```